# How to retrieve a folder or document with a hash in the name using ms graph api

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, error, microsoft-graph

I am using MS graph API to retrieve folder contents and graphs from SharePoint online, using URLs like `[...]/drive/root:/folder1/folder2:/`. The folder and document names are of course URL encoded.

It seems to work fine for all allowable characters in folder and document names except for # which just returns a 404 error every time.

**Edit 20 Nov**

It seems the problem only occurs if the # is immediately preceded by an &. For example, create a folder called `a#&b` and you can fetch this by URL encoding it as `...:/a%23%26b:` - everything works no problem. But if you create a folder called `a&#b` you cannot fetch it by url encoding it as `...:/a%26%23b:`

So it seems this is just an obscure bug in MS graph (or maybe even in whatever SharePoint API it sits on top of). Since the sequence `&#` is used in HTML, I'd guess they're trying to detect where the caller has mistakenly used HTML encoding and recover from it.

This isn't a real use case for my customer but just something I stumbled upon while trying to test it would work with all possible filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this issue as below:

1. Created a folder with special character #

[image]

2. Retrieve this folder

[image]

3. Encode this special character (%23)

[image]

BR

Comment: Hmm thanks let me try it again, maybe I did something stupid

Comment: I've discovered it only happens with the sequence `&#` - see my edit to the original post above. Thanks again for making me re-investigate :)